Effective Methods for Integrating Two-Dimensional Vector Fields with Significant Local Maxima
I have discretized two dimensional vector field data ($\partial S(h, T)/\partial h, \partial S(h, T)/\partial T$). I am using cumtrapz function from Scipy to integrate the $\partial S(h, T)/\partial T$ data for a fixed $h$ using the following definition: $S(T) - S(\infty) = \int_{\infty}^{T} \frac{\partial S}{\partial T} dT$. As the derivatives fluctuate widely at some places, the contours look really wiggly and not perpendicular to the local vector field. How to find a way around this problem to construct the contour plot of the vector field S(h,T)?
The following is the link to find the vector field data. You can read the file as $[ h, T, \frac{\partial S(h, T)}{\partial h}, \frac{\partial Sh, T)}{\partial T} ]$

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/sit7z7l83u5278lpxt9ie/data_entropy.txt?rlkey=zxjzqx4tdlfp9p3wtj10axk9j&dl=0

This is my Python code to integrate the data and plot the entropy contour.
import os  
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + '/Library/TeX/texbin'  
print(os.getenv("PATH"))  

import matplotlib  
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
from labellines import labelLine, labelLines  
import scipy.optimize as opt  
import itertools  
from symfit import Parameter, Variable  
a = Parameter('a')  
b = Parameter('b')  
x = Variable('x')  
powerlaw = a*(x**b)  
from symfit import Fit  
from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, LogLocator)  
from matplotlib import ticker  
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter, NullFormatter  
import matplotlib as mpl  
mpl.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300  
plt.rcParams.update({  
    "text.usetex": True,  
    "font.family": "serif",  
    #"font.sans-serif": ["Helvetica"]  
})  

from matplotlib import cm  
import pandas as pd  
from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz  

plt.rc('xtick',labelsize=14)  
plt.rc('ytick',labelsize=14)  
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size':14})  

data = pd.read_csv("data_entropy.txt", header=None, delim_whitespace=True)  
data.head()  

x = data[0].values # fields  
y = data[1].values # temperature  
u = data[2].values  
v = data[3].values  

h = np.unique(x) # Unique Fields  
T = np.unique(y) # Unique Temperatures  

dSdh = u.reshape(len(h), len(T)) # dS/dH values  
dSdT = v.reshape(len(h), len(T)) # dS/dT values  

X, Y = np.meshgrid(T, h)  

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))  

S = np.zeros((len(h),len(T)))  
S_temp = cumtrapz(y=dSdT, x=T, initial = 0.0)  

for i in range(len(h)):  
    for j in range(len(T)):  
        S[i][j] = S_temp[i][j] - S_temp[i][len(T)-1]  + np.log(4.0*np.pi)  

contour = ax1.contourf(X, Y, S, cmap=cm.coolwarm)  
contour_lines = ax1.contour(X, Y, S, colors='k', levels=np.arange(-3.2, 3.2, 0.5))  

ax1.set_xlabel(r'T/J')  
ax1.set_ylabel(r'h/J')  
ax1.set_title('Entropy Contour without gradient')  
ax1.set_xlim(0.01,0.5)  
ax1.set_ylim(0.0,8.0)  
cbar = plt.colorbar(contour)  

plt.savefig('Entropy Contour wo gradient.png',bbox_inches='tight')  

fig, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))  
ax2.quiver(X, Y, dSdT*(0.5-0.01)/8.0, dSdh, label='Vector Field')  
contour = ax2.contour(X, Y, S, cmap=cm.coolwarm)  
ax2.set_xlabel(r'T/J')  
ax2.set_ylabel(r'h/J')  
ax2.set_title('Entropy Contour with gradient')  
ax2.legend(loc='upper right')  
ax2.set_xlim(0.01,0.5)  
ax2.set_ylim(0.0,8.0)  
plt.savefig('Entropy Contour w gradient.png',bbox_inches='tight')  

Find my current plots here.

https://imgur.com/a/KpvfV9N

